# Object wont follow with root rotation X

Tags: animation, armature

Hi I want the top of roof follow along with my root rotation how can I do that

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use a local space.**

Concur with [@moonboots](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/234138/15543) that the issue is the limit rotation constraint.

[image]

IMO the constraint needs to be in a local space.

Just as the  tipper is controlled "locally" by the hydraulics, the constraint should be looking at local transforms.  Using WORLD brings the world orientation into play.

[image]
*For example limiting to 0 world space rotation.  The rotation gizmo is, as above,  in LOCAL mode, notice  it is also aligned globally, to global z axis.  Changing limit to 90 degrees would align to global horizontal.  If we start to  rotate (steer) the truck, it will bring more unexpected behaviour into play*

For the most part can consider the UI value of bones local space, in this case, :

- Tipper down is zero rotation in local space.
- Because of the edit mode alignent of dump bone, Tipper Up is a negative rotation degrees in local space.  Get value by temporarily changing bone to Euler.  Demo in gif of rotation about X.
- Rolling the bone in edit mode by 180 degrees flips rotation to positive.
- Consider adding limit rotations to zero on other axes.)
- Also changing the bones rotation mode, for what is ultimately a simple hinge,  consider using the  axis angle rotation mode where, in this case,  the x axis is the hinge axis.

Answer (score 1):

Select the bone and disable or remove its *Limit Rotation* constraint:

[image]